# splitting large file into small files

Tags: bash, python-3.x, awk

I have a text file which has thousands of number values like
1
2
3
4
5
.
.
.
.
n

I know we can use awk to separate these values. But is there a way in which one can fetch first 10,20,40,80,160....,n values in different text files.

I was using python to do so but it takes a lot of time to separate these files.Here is the sample code for python

```
import numpy as np
from itertools import islice
data = np.loadtxt('ABC.txt',
                 unpack=True,
                 delimiter=',',
                 skiprows=1)
n = 10
iterator = list(islice(data[0], n))
for item in range(n):
np.savetxt('output1.txt',iterator,delimiter=',',fmt='%10.5f')

iterator = list(islice(data[0], n*2))
for item in iterator:
np.savetxt('output2.txt', iterator, delimiter=',',fmt='%10.5f')

iterator = list(islice(data[0], n*4))
for item in iterator:
np.savetxt('output3.txt', iterator, delimiter=',',fmt='%10.5f')

iterator = list(islice(data[0], n*8))
for item in iterator:
np.savetxt('output4.txt', iterator, delimiter=',',fmt='%10.5f')
```

and so on.

Is there a better way to do this in bash or in python. Thank you in advance!

Comment: `np.loadtxt` loads everything at once into memory. You need an iterator. The standard Python's `open` provides an iterator interface. You'll have to do the parsing yourself, though.

Comment: What is the desired result? A bunch of files, each having data from the first column and 10, 20,...n first rows? How large is your _n?_

Comment: @9000 : Yes, you are correct and the files has around 36000 entries

Answer (score 1, accepted):

an inefficient but quick to implement apprach

```
s=5; for i in {1..10}; do ((s*=2)); head -$s file > sub$i; done
```

since the files are overlapping, there will be better ways, but based on the size of the file and how many times it needs to be repeated this might be good enough.

Answer (score 1):

You didn't provide any sample input and expected output and the text of your questions is ambiguous so this is just a guess but this MAY be what you're looking for:

```
$ seq 1000 | awk -v c=10 'NR==c{print; c=2*c}'
10
20
40
80
160
320
640
```

If not then edit your question to clarify.

Answer (score 1):

SED is your friend:

```
$ numlines=$( wc -l big_text_file.txt | cut -d' ' -f1 )

$ step=100

$ echo $numlines
861

$ for (( ii=1; ii<=$numlines; ii+=$step )); do echo $ii,$(( ii+step-1 ))w big_text_file.${ii}.txt; done > break.sed

$ cat break.sed
1,100w big_text_file.1.txt
101,200w big_text_file.101.txt
201,300w big_text_file.201.txt
301,400w big_text_file.301.txt
401,500w big_text_file.401.txt
501,600w big_text_file.501.txt
601,700w big_text_file.601.txt
701,800w big_text_file.701.txt
801,900w big_text_file.801.txt

$ sed -n -f break.sed big_text_file.txt 

$ wc -l big_text_file*.txt
   100 big_text_file.101.txt
   100 big_text_file.1.txt
   100 big_text_file.201.txt
   100 big_text_file.301.txt
   100 big_text_file.401.txt
   100 big_text_file.501.txt
   100 big_text_file.601.txt
   100 big_text_file.701.txt
    61 big_text_file.801.txt
   861 big_text_file.txt
  1722 total
```

Comment: Well, you're just no fun! :P